# Lets encript certificate not valid on windows server 2019

Tags: windows, ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I have a host https://arcgis.linearbench.com

I created this certificate with win-acme (letsencrypt windows client) and the certificate is valid on other machines. However, it shows "windows does not have enough information to verify this certificate" error when I view the certificate in IIS certificate store. A browser on the server machine shows invalid certificate. And this error prevent .net application working. Is intermediate certificates missing on the server? How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: windows can not found `R3`

Comment: SSL Diag can teach you more, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Comment: In most cases, the problems with the certificate verification occur due to lack of proper certificates installed on your system. Consequently, the same goes for Windows doesn't have enough information to verify this certificate error. You can resolve this error by reinstalling affected certificates.